# Connection times out when I add ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I am trying to add ssl to my website using this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04). The browser is redirected to https://www.example.com but then it times out. I've looked at similar questions on here with no luck. Is there anything I'm missing? Please see my nginx config below (actual domain name removed):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
       }

server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;

        root /var/www/example/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }


        location /blog/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$query_string;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server is listening for http on port 443, not https. Change your listen line to

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

If you build Nginx to enable http2 it might look like this

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
```

You can compare your config to the ones I've posted on [this page](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/#wpmu-nginx-configuration-files), which all work. That same tutorial also shows you how to build Nginx with http2 enabled - it's surprisingly easy.

Answer (score 0):

Change `server-name` and `redirect` parameters from example to your real site name. Then restart nginx

```
# sudo service nginx restart
```

And check that ngnix service is running

```
# sudo service nginx status
```

Comment: I don't think the user is actually using example.com, because https://www.example.com does actually serve a site.